# Dictionary of list as tree class

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tree

I am trying to define a tree class that can be easily managed (add nodes, get children and walk through it in dfs or bfs style) but I know just a little about python and I'm stuck with an error when running my code:

> AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'get'

This is my code, by now I've just implemented the addition of nodes:

```
class Tree(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self = {}

    def add(self, node, child):
        if self.get(int(node)):
            childs = self.get(int(node))
            childs.append(int(child))
            self.update({int(node):childs})
        else:
            self.update({int(int(node)):[int(child)]})

def main():
    tot = int(input("Cantidad de relaciones: "))
    t = Tree()
    for i in range (0, tot):
        for i in range (0,1):
            a = []
            a.extend(input().split())
        t.add(a[0], a[1])
    print(t)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit it from `dict`!

`get` and `update` is dictionary datatype's methods.

Your code: `class Tree(object):` replace it with: `class Tree(dict):` and error will be resolved.

Also your idea with your code is strage. Python already implements tree-like data structures with `dict` and `list` datatypes.

```
a = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': {
        'c': [33, 44, 55]
        'd': 123,
    }
}
```

[Python data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: That's it.. Thanks! I have another issue now, I don't know why but it's not generating the list but it is overriding the values and keys.. for instance if I do add this relations: 1 2, 1 3; the dict has {1:3} instead of {1:[2,3]}

Comment: I think you just split input string by space `input().split()`. And add it to dictionary as key with value.
You need a more comprehensive approach

Comment: no, the mistake was that I initialized the dict with the value as just a number, not as a list.. now it's working (I'll edit my code so that everyone can see)